# Adding BigQuery query result in an already existing report in Google Data Studio(Looker Studio)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have an already existing Google Data Studio(Looker Studio) Report where the data is coming from a Google BigQuery table. Now when I am making a new query using that table and trying to attach the query result in the existing data studio report, it is not hapenning. Basically I am not getting any option to attach the query result in the already existing data studio report. Need help regarding this issue.

First I ran the query on a table in bigquery and exported the result in a data studio report. Now when i am running another query on the same table, I can't able to add the new result in the already existing dashboard report. When I am exporting the query result, every time it is generating a new dashboard report.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Big Query table as a data source in your report, each time that Looker Studio document is loaded or its filters are updated, Looker Studio will run a query to the data source to fetch data. You should have no problem to display new info in your report if you insert the new rows in the right table.

As you mention you are trying to update the data with a query result, you can write the result to the datasource table as destination table.

Comment: No issue regarding the new data or a new record. The issue is related to a new query.  Whenever I am writing a new query in Bigquery console, the result after running the query is not getting added to the same Data studio report. It is always opening a new report.

Comment: If you need default filter configuration you can set them up in the report Edit configuration. If what you want is a datasource with “always where”, you can go two ways: A) create a new datasource with a custom query or B) go to Big Query and create a new view with that custom conditions and make that view your datasource.